# Flow control with for loops and on.load event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through an array of images and drawing them on a canvas. The problem is that the images are being downloaded from the server first, so I need to wait until they fully load before attempting to draw them. Sounds straight-forward enough, but I'm having trouble controlling the flow. I wrote an example snippet below to demonstrate:

```
var drawImages = function(myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        console.log("1");
        $(imageObj).on('load', function(){
            //draw image
            console.log("2");
        });
        console.log("3");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the console output is as follows:

```
1
3
2
```

Which makes sense, since "2" happens after the image fully loads. But I need it to happen sequentially.

The problem seems to be that the for loop doesn't care until the on.load event finishes before moving on to the next iteration. So if there are multiple images in the array, the output becomes:

```
1
3
1
3
//image finishes loading...
2
```

Is there a way to stall the iteration until the image loads? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Does the drawing code need all of the images before you can start drawing or can it draw the images onto canvas as they are downloaded?

Comment: It can draw the images as they are loaded.

Comment: If you are happy to draw them as they are loaded, then why do you need the `console.log('3');` code at all? Just draw them in the `load` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array contains the image URLs and you want to draw the images as they are loaded, then what you have will work. Just create the image elements, and set the listeners on them, e.g:

```
var drawImages = function(myArray) {
  var image;

  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    image = new Image();
    $('#hidden-loader-div').append(image);
    $(image).on('load', function(){
        //draw image
        console.log("2");
    });
    // Start the loading process
    image.src = myArray[i];
  }
}
```

The load function will trigger whenever the image is loaded. Just make sure to have a `<div>` somewhere that you can stick these images into. It doesn't have to be visible.

Comment: Having the array contain the URLs is a good idea. I was constructing each image's URL inside the loop itself using image ids from the array, and that was throwing off the order.